# Recode string into a binary matrix

Tags: r, matrix, binary

I would like to recode some strings into binary mode for codifing them into matrices, in R. Let's say I have the following strings in a data frame:

```
strings  code
ABC       1
BCA       2
CAB       1
```

After extracting them I have the following strings:

"ABC"
"BCA"
"CAB"

And I would like to implement the next transformation:

```
A = 100
B = 010
C = 001
```

So that transforming "ABC" into the next matrix

```
100
010
001
```

And so, "BCA" into:

```
010
001
100
```

And "CAB" into:

```
001
100
010
```

And, after this transformation, getting a vector for "ABC" that is:

```
100010001
```

which represents ABC, an so on.

Basically, what I want to do is defining an algorithm with binary dictionary for letters characters so that it converts each letter into a binary sequence using R.

I've tried some aproaches but could not get a nice function...

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a named vector, then split and match.

```
dictionary <- setNames(c("100", "010", "001"), LETTERS[1:3])

x <- c("ABC", "BCA", "CAB")

sapply(strsplit(x, ""), function(i)
  paste(dictionary[ i ], collapse = ""))

# [1] "100010001" "010001100" "001100010"
```

Or instead of creating custom dictionary, why not use real binary?

```
sapply(x, function(i)
  paste(rawToBits(charToRaw(i)), collapse = ""))

# ABC 
# "010000000000010000010000000001000101000000000100" 
# BCA 
# "000100000000010001010000000001000100000000000100" 
# CAB 
# "010100000000010001000000000001000001000000000100"
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use a `gsub`.  Create a key/value `list` ('lst'), Loop through the sequence of 'lst', use `gsub` to match the `names` of the 'lst', replace with the 'value' and assing it back to 'strings' column

```
lst <- list(A = '100', B = '010', C = '001')
for(i in seq_along(lst)) df1$strings <- gsub(names(lst)[[i]], lst[[i]], df1$strings)
df1
#    strings code
#1 100010001    1
#2 010001100    2
#3 001100010    1
```